# How can i animate the swaying motion of the herbs when the character's hand touches them?

Tags: physics, dynamic

I'm trying to make an animation that includes scenes of the tea-making process from harvesting to brewing. Do you guys know the best way to make the flowers/herbs sway slightly when the character's hand touches them?

[image: Example for what I mean]

Comment: Hi and welcome. There are several options and it depends on your model and how realistic you want it to be. Cloth sim, Soft body sim, armature, mesh deform modifier, Geometry/Simulation nodes, etc. Have you already tried something? How does the model look like?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! I've never actually tried the physics and simulations. Most of the time I have to spend on the character animation and now I have a project that has some plant stuff in the animation so I think it's better to start learning it now. I don't have a specific model but you can imagine them as potted plants that are grown indoors and will have a character plucking their leaves or flowers. So there will be a force that causes it to swing. If you have an idea for this case, please let me know :))